# XCode Instruments collects no data

Tags: ios, xcode, mobile-safari, xcode-instruments

I'm trying to debug a potential javascript memory leak on iOS.  My approach (was) to monitor Mobile Safari on my iPad using Instruments, but there's a problem:  no matter what process I attach Instruments to, I get no data at all.  After setting up the items to watch and starting the monitor, it runs along happily, but shows no memory usage, no CPU usage, nothing.  Is there something I need to do with my iPad or Instruments to enable collection of this data?

Comment: I have the same problem. Sometimes Instruments works for a few hours then it's completely stop. Restarting Instruments, my device or my mac doesn't help. I haven't seen any system in when it work or doesn't, or why it sometimes works again. Now it hasn't worked for days..

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue with xCode 6 where the instruments would show like it's recording data although there was no actual data presented or collected.
Restarting my Mac Mini, restarting xCode, cleaning the build and disconnecting and connecting my iPad did not solve this issue.
However, my other devices were profiling just fine.

The solution I found is to reboot the iPad. (You reboot your device holding the home button and the power button for a few seconds. Then to turn it on again you press the power button).
This solved this issue and I was told it can solve other xCode related issues like when your program keep running on Debug even when you run it on Release.

Hope this helps.